# Why does iterating over a set of linux files always return 1 even when no matches?

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I am iterating over a set of files with:

```
for F in *.note.*; do echo "File is $F"; done
```

If five files match I might get the following output:

```
File is a_dispatch.note.23-MAY-16
File is b_dispatch.note.25-MAY-16
File is x_dispatch.note.25-MAY-16
File is y_dispatch.note.25-MAY-16
File is z_dispatch.note.25-MAY-16
```

However when no files are matched, e.g. by running:

```
for F in *.nomatch.*; do echo "File is $F"; done
```

I get:

```
File is *.nomatch.*
```

Now, if no files match I clearly don't want to take any action. Where I am simply doing an echo of the filename in this example I might have significant processing which won't want to be executed when there are no files.

What am I missing here? Why am I getting the loop executed when no files matched?

Comment: Please search before posting. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84826/looping-over-a-folder-enter-anyways-the-loop) on *Unix and Linux*.

Comment: place `shopt -s nullglob`  before your loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for F in *.note.*; do test -f  $F && echo "File is $F"; done
```

Break down :

```
    for F in *.note.*;
    do
        test -f  $F
        if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];then

        echo "File is $F";
        fi
    done
```